# Collectionview with embeded tableview is clipped when rotating screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, constraints

I have created a collectionview with a tableview embeded into the collectionview cell. The idea is that the collectionview makes it able to scroll horizontal, while the tableview makes it able to scroll vertical for each section. Everything is set up in storyboard using autolayout, and works as it should, the only issue is that when i rotate the screen from portrait to landscape, the top if the collectionview or tableview is clipped.

How it currently looks in Portait mode

[image]

How it currently looks in Landscape mode (This is where the problem is)

[image]

I have attached two images: 1 from portait mode, which is how it should look like, and a second image of landscape mode, where the first item in the tableview and the tableview header is clipped. I suspect something in the view is not updated correct, but i am not sure what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it just the scroll or the top part of the cell is clipped?

Comment: I am able to scroll up to see the first cell and the tableview header, but it quicly bounces back again

Comment: It means your tableview is being drawing above the screen. Can you confirm if the cell size of collectionview is different for portrait vs landscape?

Comment: Hmm its seems the cell sizes are the same when rotated: 

in portait mode: 
Width of cell 375.0
Height of cell 535.0

in landscape mode: 
Width of cell 375.0
Height of cell 535.0

Comment: check your sizeForItem delegate method. It should have conditions to check if it is portrait or landscape and return different size for each case

Comment: You're right, thanks for the help, really appreciate your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please set collection view cell width equal of collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.width
    let height: CGFloat = SET_HEIGHT_THAT_YOU_WANT //collectionView.frame.size.height
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

don't forget to set UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout